# Formula inside a variable

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following question, is it posible to insert a formula inside a variable in VBA Excel to use this variable after?
For example:

```
MinO = "=MIN(" & .Cells(3, 7 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(3, 9 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ")"

For N = 1 To NumSheet + 1
    .Cells(4, 5 + N).Value = 80 * ((.Cells(3, 8 + NumSheet).Value - .Cells(3, 5 + N).Value) / (.Cells(3, 8 + NumSheet).Value - MinO))
    .Cells(4, 5 + N).Font.Bold = True
Next N
```

So MinO is a variable with a formula inside, I know in `Range().Formula` it works but how can I make it work using a variable?
I know there is also the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min` but I want to see if it's posible doing it the other way as WorksheetFunction sometimes give me some errors.

Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: Take a look at the `Evaluate` method.

Comment: Yes, I’ve checked it but I don’t know how to make it work using ```Cells()```

Comment: I found the way using evaluate(), thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but therefore you need the [`Evaluate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) function. (The URL refers to the official documentation of that function)

So, in your case, you might use: (seems not to be completely correct, so I'll put it in comment)

```
' .Cells(4, 5 + N).Value = 80 * ((.Cells(3, 8 + NumSheet).Value - .Cells(3, 5 + N).Value) / (.Cells(3, 8 + NumSheet).Value - Evaluate(MinO)))
```

As mentioned in below comments, the following seems to be the correct approach:

```
MinO = Evaluate("=MIN(" & .Cells(3, 7 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(3, 9 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ")")
```

Comment: Will `Evaluate (Min(...)` do something different than `WorksheetFunction.Min`?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: But then OP likely will run into the same issues he has mentioned using `WorksheetFunction.Min` - just in a much more complicated form.

Comment: I see, but if I put ```MinO = "=MIN(" & .Cells(3, 7 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(3, 9 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ")"``` it throws me an error 13 there. So I have to rewrite that line too.

Comment: You may need to remove the starting `"=` in the formula string. It is not a formula in a cell.

Comment: I did that but it still gives me the error, I’ve seen it works using ```A1:A2``` but I don’t know if it works using ```.Cells(1,1):.Cells(1,2)``` and I have to use the second option as the cells change related to the variable ```NumSheet```

Comment: The range that gives you an error may have some formulae resulting in error values (i.e. look for errors inside your ranges)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `Evaluate` needs the `=`

Comment: Okay, I have found a way, it was using Evaluate() here: ```MinO = Evaluate("=MIN(" & .Cells(3, 7 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(3, 9 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ")")```. And not in the other part, so thank you. I’ll take your answer as the correct one! :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I work with formulas from excel i write them in cell (check that everything works) and then in VBA immediate window (CTRL+G) I type

```
 ? Activecell.Formula
```

or

```
 ? Activecell.FormulaR1C1
```

And it displays formula that you need... That is good start then you start changing parts to reflect your desired variable changes.

Remember that this output is string and in code needs to start and end with 1x", when you want to add string in formula you need to add "" also sometimes you need to add """" and """ for strings in string... :)

Comment: Thank you, but I finally found a way using Evaluate(), although I'll take your option into account :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this will work, as it is basically just a text string. I believe that you try to look into why the Application.WorksheetFunction is giving errors instead, or creating your own function if you have some special cases that the worksheet function cannot handle.

Comment: I’ll try that too, thanks. I don’t know why it gives me issues because when I use the Min function it does not calculate the min of the range, it just takes one of the values of the range but not the min.

Comment: That basic text string can be processed by `Evaluate()`